# CodeIgniter - Login is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working with admin page. I logged in my username and password correctly but it says "404 Page Not Found - The page you requested was not found."

This is the controller:

```
public function login()
{
    $header = array("title" => "Welcome - ");
    $this->load->view('includes/header', $header);
    $this->load->view('accounts/login');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}

public function login_submit()
{
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password'))
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|is_unique[accounts.username]|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');

    $accountDetails = $this->accounts_model->fetch('accounts', $data);
    if (!$accountDetails) {
        echo "<script>alert('Account does not exist!'); window.location.href = '".base_url()."accounts/login';</script>";
    } else {
        $accountDetails = $accountDetails[0];
        if ($accountDetails->status == 1) {
            $header = array("title" => "Account - ");
            $this->load->view('includes/header', $header);
            $this->load->view('admin/home', $accountDetails);
            $this->load->view('includes/footer');     
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('You account is blocked!'); window.location.href = '".base_url()."accounts/login';</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the view page: http://prntscr.com/h9eog8

Comment: You have no form validation run() https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Oh yes. But still not working. :(

Comment: Might be some thing in your model function

Comment: @wolfgang1983 This is the model function - http://prntscr.com/h9f39h

Comment: Have you setting base_url in config.php file? and can you share full controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code will help you..Works fine

plz set your form like this:

```
<form action='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/accounts/login_submit' method='post' name='process'>
```

**accounts Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/* Author: Pedram shabani
 * Description: accounts controller class
 */
class accounts extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

   public function login($msg = NULL)
{
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $header = array("title" => "Welcome - ");
    $this->load->view('includes/header', $header);
    $this->load->view('accounts/login',$data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}

public function login_submit()
{
     $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
     $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
      $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password'))
      );
        $this->load->model('accounts_model');
        $accountDetails = $this->accounts_model->fetch($data);
      if(! $accountDetails){
            // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
            $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
            $this->login($msg);
        }else{
            $this->load->helper('url'); 
            $header = array("title" => "Welcome - ");
            $this->load->view('includes/header', $header);
            $this->load->view('accounts/login',$data);
            $this->load->view('includes/footer');
        }
}

}
?>
```

accounts_model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class accounts_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function fetch ($data){
   // die(var_dump($data));
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
        $this->db->where('password', $data['password']);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $num = $query->num_rows();
        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
          $row = $query->row();
          $data = array(
                    'userid' => $row->userid,
                    'fname' => $row->fname,
                    'lname' => $row->lname,
                    'username' => $row->username,
                    'validated' => true
                    );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }
          return false;
    }

}
?>
```

and at the end.plz set default controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
```

Comment: This is the form: prntscr.com/h9eog8

Comment: This is the model: prntscr.com/h9f39h